# Password Hash Synchronization heartbeat was skipped in last 120 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, fips

I received an email for my organization that password hash sync heartbeat has been skipped in the last 120 minutes.
In the remediation steps,  I have been asked to restart Microsoft Azure AD Sync on the VM and  If FIPS compliance is enabled for your machine(s), please disable password hash sync to remediate this alert.

So, what is the best possible solution so that password hash sync is not skipped in future.

Also, is being FIPS compliant necessary?

Answer (score 0):

> You need to follow the below mentioned steps to prevent password hash sync heartbeat from being skipped.

1. Check the

   - Azure AD Sync service is running on the VM.
   - If there are any network connectivity issues between the VM and Azure AD.
   - If there are any issues with the Azure AD Connect configuration.
   - If FIPS compliance is enabled for your machine(s), disable password hash sync to remediate this alert.

[image]

**Enabling MD5 for password hash Sync**

- In %programfiles%\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin and Open miiserver.exe.config.
- And check the configuration or runtime node at the end of the file, and add the node  `<enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>`

```
<configuration>
        <runtime>
            <enforceFIPSPolicy enabled="false"/>
        </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

For further information, refer to the [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/connect/how-to-connect-password-hash-synchronization)

Comment: Yes. All these settings are correct for now.

What do I do to ensure this does not happen again?

Comment: You can enable the EnforceCloudPasswordPolicyForPasswordSyncedUsers feature, which will remove the DisablePasswordExpiration value from PasswordPolicies during the next password hash sync for each user, upon their next password change in on-premises AD. You can also update the Azure AD password policy to match the AD policy by using the Set-MsolPasswordPolicy PowerShell command.